# Save data to server data base in Android give unexpected error and close

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

i make a application for track geo location and save that data to server mysql database. when i run the application is it show unexpected error and close application. some times geolocation is not pointing. but when i comment that save code geo location tracking working nicely. cant find what is the exact problem in this 
here my code

```
///////////////// this is the updated locations/////////////

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());


    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadSave();

    // Report to the UI that the location was updated

}

public void loadSave() {
            String mydataurl = "http://myrul.com/saveData.php";
        //String type = params[0];
    try {

        String longi = "aaa"; // Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        String lati = "aare";//Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        String user = "a";
        String code = "b";
        String date = "c";
        URL url = new URL(mydataurl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("longi", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(longi, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("lati", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lati, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("code", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(code, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("date", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(date, "UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(mydataurl);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
                } catch (MalformedInputException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**STACK TRACE**

[image]

Comment: Could you add a stacktrace?

Comment: Stack-traceFATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.mapdemo, PID: 847
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
 at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl

Comment: You can't make network calls on the main thread.  Look into AsyncTasks.

Comment: can u little explain about this? means i have to make this loadSave() in another class or what i exactly want to do to fix this problem

Comment: You need to do the network request in a separate thread.  If you move the network request inside of loadSave() into an AsyncTask, things should work for you! See examples here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Please copy the text of your exception next time

Comment: thanks can u publish correct code. because i new to android

Answer (score 0):

Android thought this exception because you executed network task on main thread. You have execute this task on other thread by put it to an AsyncTask.

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            loadSave();
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: thanks can u publish full code set where i want to add this.. because i new to android

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadSave();

Comment: i change code like you said but there is an error
 cannot find symbol class AsyncTask

E:\android-google-maps-demo-master\app\src\main\java\com\example\mapdemo\MapDemoActivity.java
Error:(212, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AsyncTask

c
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: Have you imported AsyncTask to your class

Comment: thanks friend.. now it working without errors. but data is not save to DB.. why is that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110093/discussion-between-chara-and-hoang-v-nam).

Comment: here my php code
require "DB_Connection.php";

$longi =$_POST["longi"];
$lati = $_POST["lati"];
$user = $_POST["user"];
$lisence =$_POST["lisence"];
$date = $_POST["date"];

$query1="INSERT INTO mapdata (longi,lati,user,lisence,date)
values ('".$longi."','".$lati."','".$user."','".$lisence."', '".$date."' )";

mysql_query($query1) or die ('Error :' . mysql_error());